# ColumnTransformer Pipeline not returning feature names

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to return the features created within a pipeline in order to plot feature importance with the corresponding column name later. However, i get *"Transformer day (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names."* error despite it being defined in the class below.

```
class DatesTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Transforms date column to datetime and add features with 
    year, month and day of week. Excludes the date columns in the end.
    """
    drop_col : bool = True

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.dates = pd.to_datetime(X["date_time"])
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X["month"]     = self.dates.dt.month
        if self.drop_col:
            X.drop(["date_time"], axis=1, inplace=True)

        self.columns = columns

        return X

    def get_feature_names(self):
        return X.columns.tolist()
```

```
#Pipeline for dates attributes
date_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ("dates_transformer", DatesTransformer()),
        ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
        ("cat_encoder", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))
    ])
```

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ("day",  date_pipeline,    day_features)])
```

Pipeline is fitted then using the following code:

```
X_train = full_pipeline.fit_transform(train)
print(X_train.shape)
X_valid = full_pipeline.fit_transform(valid)
print(X_valid.shape)
```

This is where i get my error unfortunately.

```
full_pipeline.get_feature_names()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you fitted the pipeline?

Comment: Yes, forgot to include the code. I've edit my post

Comment: Apparently it is not supported, see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2007